# How to pass current installer.msi name to custom action?

Tags: c#, wix, custom-action

My custom action is running fine and getting values like [ProductName] but now i want to get the current installer name. Installer name means the output setup.msi filename.

Comment: You've already asked almost the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63647768/how-to-pass-installer-name-to-custom-action-and-store-in-a-text-file)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski this one is different... the topic is same but the question is different because in that question the custom action was not working. Now its working and also storing other data passed to the custom action in a text file.

Comment: Now the problem is i don't know how to get the installer name. and pass it to the custom action..

Comment: System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;
i tried this ... but it returns this custom action name.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`[OriginalDatabase]` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/originaldatabase) contains the original name of your MSI file.